# How to port a Python application to Linux that works fine in Windows

Tags: python, windows, linux, ioerror

I am having trouble porting a working, Windows Python application to Linux. I am having some problems, because I did not write the code and am just learning Python. I am having  trouble fixing the issues that it keeps throwing up. So here is a kind of error that right now I am stuck with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "alpha_beta", line 237, in <module>
main()
File "alpha_beta", line 185, in main
ABCCmd()
File "alpha_beta.py", line 74, in ABCCmd

File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\shutil.py", line 80, in copy
File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\shutil.py", line 47, in copyfile
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/myPath/XFiles.bin.addr_patched
```

Any pointers on how to fix it will be much appreciated

Edit:

1) What I mean by I am stuck is, the traceback of the error goes to C:\softs\Python\Lib but actually I am currently executing this code in Ubuntu. Why would the traceback reference to windows library

2) Another thing that bothers me is it says there is an IOError.But when I try to add permission for the denied one it gives me a chmod: changing permissions of /myPath/xFiles.bin.addr_patched': Operation not permitted
Edit 2:

I had commented out a module because I thought it wasn't very useful. Since Now I am anyway discussing the porting issues, I thought I can bring  up this additional problem as well since I think the issue is the same and the fix should be similar. On including #pdb module in the python code, I get the following error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "alpha_beta", line 6, in <module>
import pdb
File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\pdb.py", line 14, in <module>
File "C:\softs\Python\Lib\pprint.py", line 39, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cStringIO
```

I looked at the importer_Cache and looks like this

```
'': None, '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2': None, '/usr/lib/python2.6/': None
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0': None, '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk': None,
'/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old': <imp.NullImporter object at 0x7f1269048070>, '/usr/
/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0': None, '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL': None,
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages': None, '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages':
None
```

***SOLVED** : *There was a weird wrapper in the script which was causing the python script to execute from a different location. Still don't understand how though. After modifying my script to just directly execute as python myScript.py it runs fine. Thank you all anyway for the help*

Comment: Looks like you don't have write permissions for that file?

Comment: Can you do better than "I'm stuck!"?  What do you not understand about the traceback?

Comment: @cha0site I tried adding permissions by including chmod +x in my shell script but I ran into chmod: changing permissions of `/myPath/XFiles.bin.addr_patched': Operation not permitted

Comment: Fix your permissions. If you don't have the requisite permissions to do so, get the system admin to do it.

Comment: @ExceptionHandler: A. `chmod +w`, you need write perms not execute perms. B. It appears you're not the owner of that file. Also, now that I'm looking at that traceback, I don't understand if it's linux or windows? What's that `C:\` doing there?

Comment: Where are you running this program that you're getting Windows paths in your error messages?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I am running the python script in Ubuntu. The thing to be noted is,this script was originally written for a windows based application. Now I am trying to modify and use the same script for a linux based application. But unable to do so because I did not write the python code and I don't understand these references that well myself

Comment: I wonder if the import machinery has been adjusted.  What does `sys.path_importer_cache` look like at the point the error is raised?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I have edited my question further. Can you please take a look at the edited question again

Answer (score 3):

The mixture of Windows and Unix style paths in your error messages makes me think that you may have some filenames that are hard coded or manually created using os specific path separators ('\' or '/').  If you can figure out where the `gOptions.inputTf` and `gWorkingTfFile` values are assigned you should look into using [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to help you use the correct paths.

```
from os.path import join

file = join('A', 'B')
# 'A/B' on unix systems
# 'A\B' on windows systems
```

Comment: Actually this is weirder because it seems as if the Python script is *finding* that path. As if he actually has a file named `C:\softs\Python\Lib\shutil.py` somewhere in Python's PATH. Note that that's a single filename with no directories.

Comment: @istruble I agree with cha0site because if there was a path issue then it would say not found etc. But it is actually trying to find the file

Comment: Is he running his Windows Python program under Wine?

Comment: @AndrewBeals No I am not running the program under Wine

Comment: @ExceptionHandler: That file seems to exist. Can you find it?

Comment: @cha0site I tried finding that file. No luck. There is no such file  :( I am not even able to find any references to that file. I tried greping the file path generated in the error. No luck there.