# Why would shutil.copy() raise a permission exception when cp doesn't?

Tags: python, permissions, copy

shutil.copy() is raising a permissions error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy-test.py", line 3, in <module>
    shutil.copy('src/images/ajax-loader-000000-e3e3e3.gif', 'bin/styles/blacktie/images')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 118, in copy
    copymode(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 91, in copymode
    os.chmod(dst, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'bin/styles/blacktie/images/ajax-loader-000000-e3e3e3.gif'
```

copy-test.py:

```
import shutil

shutil.copy('src/images/ajax-loader-000000-e3e3e3.gif', 'bin/styles/blacktie/images')
```

I am running copy-test.py from the command line:

```
python copy-test.py
```

But running `cp` from the command line on the same file to the same destination doesn't cause an error. Why?

Comment: Could you please write the way you start the script and maybe source code of copy-test.py?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The operation that is failing is `chmod`, not the copy itself:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 91, in copymode
    os.chmod(dst, mode)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'bin/styles/blacktie/images/ajax-loader-000000-e3e3e3.gif'
```

This indicates that the file already exists and is owned by another user.

[`shutil.copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) is specified to copy permission bits.  If you only want the file contents to be copied, use `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)`, or `shutil.copyfile(src, os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src)))` if `dst` is a directory.

A function that works with `dst` either a file or a directory and does not copy permission bits:

```
def copy(src, dst):
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
        dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

Comment: @JustinY you can use `shutil.copyfile`; see above.

Comment: It was very helpful, the exact explanation!

Answer (score 4):

This form worked for me:

```
shutil.copy('/src_path/filename','/dest_path/filename')
```

Comment: To elaborate, you must specify the destination as a file path.  I.e. you can't just copy to a directory path!

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue... using `shutil.copyfile()` was a good workaround.... however, I completely FIXED the issue by simply rebooting Windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

I don't use `shutil` I  use shell command  for copy, and run shell command in python.

Code:

```
import os

my_source= '/src_path/filename'
my_dest=   '/dest_path/filename'
os.system('sudo cp ' +my_source + my_dest ) # 'sudo cp /src_path/filename /dest_path/filename '
```

and that work for me.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the user's question. The question was "why does this happen"

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of a guess, but the first thing that pops out at me:

```
'bin/styles/blacktie/images'
```

You have no trailing slash.  While I'm not sure of the implementation of `shutil.copy()`, I can tell you that `cp` will act differently depending on what OS you're running it on.  Most likely, on your system, `cp` is being smart and noticing that `images` is a directory, and copying the file into it.

However, without the trailing slash, `shutil.copy()` may be interpreting it as a file, *not* checking, and raising the exception when it's unable to create a file named `images`.

In short, try this:

```
'bin/styles/blacktie/images/'
```

Comment: Good guess but adding the trailing slash didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score -2):

Arguments must be:

```
shutil.copy('src/images/ajax-loader-000000-e3e3e3.gif', 'bin/styles/blacktie/images.ajax-loader-000000-e3e3e3.gif')
```