# Python idle: operation not permitted error

Tags: python, python-idle, macos-mojave

My friend sent me a code he wrote with a .py extension. I tried to open it with IDLE, it gives the error

> [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I am using Python 3.7.2 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.3

I checked the other answers, and I don't think `brew install python` will solve this problem.. There is no problem when I run python from terminal, or when I run it from Anaconda Navigator.

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: This is not a duplicate because I want to open the script with IDLE. I can open it from the terminal as I said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OSError: \[Error 1\] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937806/oserror-error-1-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: if would help if you could post full error here. so that we can better analyze the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is all the error. When I try to open the code it shows an error message and says `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted`. Only option I have is select OK :/

Comment: If the error message is not prefixed with `OSError: ` as in Ali's comment, it did not come from python.  How did you try to open the file with IDLE?  Did you do something in Finder or terminal?  Be specific.  In either case, it must be macOS stopping you, not IDLE or Python.