# Permission Error: [Errno 1] Operation Not permitted

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to add some .txt files to my code in pyinstaller, but when I do `pyinstaller maze.spec`, I am getting a permission error. I thought a simple sudo would fix it, but i am still getting the error.... Any Idea on what could be wrong?

Here is my error btw

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 112, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 732, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 679, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "maze.spec", line 20, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 443, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 520, in assemble
    os.remove(self.name)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/jr194/Bit Club/Test Cases/Maze_Solver_Stack/dist/maze'
```

Also, I have checked the permissions on the maze folder, and it seems that I have rwr permissions for the user, which I am sure means I am allowed to read and write in it. So i honestly am stumped on this behavior.

Comment: Try running script as root

Comment: @0xPrateek Hey, I'm quite a newb at this. What exactly do you mean by running script as root?

Comment: @Jr194 he means run with `sudo` like this:  `sudo pyinstaller maze.spec`

Comment: yeah, I did try that. It still gives me the same permission error for some reason.

Comment: How did you install pyinstaller? Did you use sudo then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get execution permission first and then execute the script. For that, run `chmod +x maze.spec` in the terminal and then try `pyinstaller maze.spec`

Comment: Hey, I tried ur suggestion, But I am still getting the same error Messages :(

Comment: Try this: `sudo chown your_username:your_groupname filename`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937806/oserror-error-1-operation-not-permitted

Answer (score 0):

You could try (from the command line, but I'm sure there's a some error in `python` file First Please Check Is There Any Error In Your `Python` File):

Well You Can Try:

```
sudo chown your_username:your_groupname filename
```

**Note**: The group is usually just your username. I feel like there's something wrong with those permissions though. Read Write Execute for everyone seems to be off. How was this file created? How did it get to be created by the user nobody?