# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'esptool.py'

Tags: python, user-permissions

I am working to update the ESP8266 firmware using ESP8266Flash.app on mac OS X.
But I have the following error when I start to flash the firmware:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'esptool.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted."
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: \[Error 1\] Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937806/oserror-error-1-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: @Orace Hi, thx for your answer. But I don't know the my groupname. Can you help me?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/590683/how-do-i-find-my-user-id-and-group-in-mac-os-x