# MacOS crontab runtime stderr: /usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file 'myscript.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python-3.x, macos, cron

When trying to run a python script via a crontab schedule:

> * * * * * /Users/myUser/Documents/Code/Tools/appName/myScript.py >>/tmp/crontab.log 2>/tmp/crontab.err

Even tried a few different permutations of `cd` in crontab and `os.chdir()` in my script:

> * * * * * cd Documents/Code/Tools/app-use_tracker/ && /usr/local/bin/python3 app-use_tracker.py >>/tmp/crontab.log 2>/tmp/crontab.err

I kept getting the error below on stderr:

> /usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file 'app-use_tracker.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

I came across this solution on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574552/10761353
but giving Python3 `Full disk access` doesn't sound like a great(secure) idea.

I even tried `777` permissions on the python3 script, but no change in behaviour

I'm hoping for one of 2 possible solutions. (or both?):

- alternative ideas on how to get the Python3 script to run, or
- ways to figure out *where* in the filesystem, if any such place exists, Python3 *can* make the requisite types of file read/writes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions require applications to get users' permission to access the their private information. This includes things like your contacts, the camera and microphone, ... and many parts of the user's home directory, including ~/Desktop, ~/Documents, ~/Downloads, etc. This system is called Transparency Consent and Control (TCC), and you can find some more general info about it in [this Apple security guide](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/security/secddd1d86a6/web) and [this Ask Different Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers).

Command-line programs aren't considered "applications", so they don't have their own permissions in this system; they inherit permissions from whatever ran them. For interactive use, that's something like Terminal.app (you probably got prompted for permission the first time you tried to do anything in ~/Documents in Terminal). For cron jobs, that's the cron daemon itself.

The simplest solution is to move the files someplace that TCC doesn't consider private. Unfortunately, its list of locations that it considers private sometimes expands from version to version, so a subdirectory that works fine now might suddenly run into restrictions after an OS update. But I'm pretty sure it'll only ever include "standard" subdirectories of the user home directory, so if you make one that isn't part of the standard set (e.g. ~/Code or ~/Scripts) it should be safe. ~/Public is also pretty clearly not going to be a restricted location. You could also put files entirely outside your home directory, like under /Users/Shared.

If that doesn't work for what your script needs to do, you may need to grant access to cron, although I'd avoid this if possible for security reasons. But if you need to, you can go to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy pane -> Privacy tab -> either Files and Folders (for partial access) or Full Disk Access (for, um, full disk access) in the sidebar, then click the padlock at the bottom and authenticate, then click the "+" button, and add /usr/sbin/cron to the list. See [this Ask Different Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378553/crontab-operation-not-permitted).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Keywords should help with future searches! I did do some quick tests, and was not able to skirt this issue by placing the script in `~/Public`, `~/scripts` (a custom folder), but `/tmp` and `/Users/Shared` seems to be able to execute the Python script! (though following a symlink outside this sandbox is another story )

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr:

> Python3, when called by crontab on MacOS, *can* access[/call .py files located in] `/Users/Shared` and `/tmp` *without* the need for granting `Full Disk Access`.

Example crontab line:

> * * * * * cd /Users/Shared && /usr/local/bin/python3 myScript.py >>/tmp/crontab.log 2>>/tmp/crontab.err

Thanks to @gordon-davisson for the jump-start given by his post!

UPDATE: Other things that don't work:

- symlinks from /Users/Share to elsewhere in th FS