# I want to kill Safari (on Mac) after midnight

Tags: macos, cron

I want to stop browsing after midnight and in order to do so:

1. I've made at /Users/sergeart/Desktop file called `goToSleep.sh`:

   pid=$(pgrep -xn "Safari")
   kill $pid
2. I've created crontab (with crontab -e) where I put

   0-59 0-6 * * * bash /Users/sergeart/Desktop/goToSleep.sh

I expect `cron` will run `goToSleep.sh` script every minute after midnight till 6am, but  unfortunately `Safari` is still working.

What do I miss?

Comment: Yep. I works just fine when I run it in the terminal :( The first command gets safari process id and the second - kills it:)

Comment: Your Desktop folder (like a number of other places in your home directory) has privacy protection restrictions in addition to the usual permissions, and by default cron jobs don't have access to it (see [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256814/macos-crontab-runtime-stderr-usr-local-bin-python3-cant-open-file-myscript)). Try putting the script somewhere other than your home directory. Also, please check the code formatting in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```bash
foo=something command $foo
```

is not at all the same thing as

```bash
foo=something
command $foo
```

The first one does *not* call `command something` but instead calls `command $foo` (for the old value of `foo`) with `something` being assigned to the environment variable `foo`.
The second one calls `command something` but does not change the environment variable `foo`.

In your specific case, I'm not sure why you even bother with a variable, you should be able to simply do

```bash
kill $(pgrep -xn "Safari")
```

Comment: Ok, I've made changes you proposed. Cron doesn't kill safari on time, I still don't get the reason why :(